# Database no longer required - how delete db from within the App?

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete SQLite database from Android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406067/how-to-delete-sqlite-database-from-android-programmatically)

In one of my Android Apps the SQLite database is no longer required. What is the prefered way to remove the database from it's app directory? Is there a convenience method or is it simply a delete against the filesystem?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Found it here: [How to delete SQLite database from Android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406067/how-to-delete-sqlite-database-from-android-programmatically)

Comment: If you found the answer then you can put it up as answer yourself and accept it. So the question will be marked answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you might have already found the answer, but in any case :

```
 mContext.deleteDatabase(<Name_Of_Your_Database>);
```