# How to delete unwanted SQL databases?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have been building an app, using SQLite to store my data. In the process, I have changed the name of the database several times. 
I test the app by uploading it to my tablet (Nexus 7).
Are the old databases still lurking around on my tablet and, if so, how would I go about deleting them?

Comment: Starting with a search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406067/how-to-delete-sqlite-database-from-android-programmatically

Comment: just "Clear-data" from app info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the old databases still lurking around on my tablet (?)

Yes. Any old databases will still be there if you have not explicitly deleted them

> how would I go about deleting them?

One of the following:

- Uninstall and re-install the app
- Go to Settings > Applications Manager > YourAppName > Clear Data
- Call [`Context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteDatabase(java.lang.String))

Realistically in the testing/debugging environment, there's no reason to delete your old databases. As long as your `SQLiteOpenHelper` is using the new database name, the old database will have no impact other than consuming storage space on your device

You can also do:

```
String[] list = context.databaseList();
for(String name : list){
    if (!name.equals(MyDatabaseOpenHelper.DATABASE_NAME))
        context.deleteDatabase(name);
}
```

Comment: I regularly uninstall the app, but not every time I change the db name. I don't remember all the names I use. Is there an easy way of seeing what databases are still there?

Comment: Yeah. Open a terminal window/command prompt and type `adb shell ls /data/data/com.mydomain.myapp/databases/`

Comment: @BlackSpike, you can also use [`Context.databaseList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#databaseList())