# Cannot delete sqlite3 database file after closing connection

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to delete a sqlite3 database file. After I close the connection and try to delete the file, I receive and error stating that the file is being used by another process. I've  been searching for an answer for a little while, but I feel like a lot of the solutions seem way more convoluted than should be necessary. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4420083) seems like exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure what it means by "Once you have your Context". Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3
import os.path

db = "data.db"
con = sqlite3.connect(db)
c = con.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE my_table (a TEXT, b TEXT, c TEXT)''')
c.execute('''INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(?,?,?)''',("test1","test2","test3"))

con.close
os.remove(db)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not really calling `con.close` (missing parentheses)